# How does constant file in react get executed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

In my react app `index.tsx` file I called a function `initYupLocale` before rendering the React app like this

```
import initLocale from "/libs/yup"

// console.log("Updating the locale")

initLocale()

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    // Components
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

In one of the components, I am defining the schema for `yup validation`

`/src/components/settings/siteForm/schema`

```
import { string, number, object } from 'yup';

console.log("Validation schema")

const siteFormValidationSchema = object().shape({
  name: string().required().max(20),
});
```

And I am using that `validationSchema` inside one of the components. The problem is, `validationSchema` is defined first before updating the `locale`. As per my understanding, since I called `initLocale` first, `locale` should be updated before `schemaValidation` is defined.

When I checked the `consoloe`, `Validation schema` gets printed first and `Updating the locale` second regardless of my current page. I am only using `siteValdationSchema` if the url is `/settings`.

Comment: Please have a look at the suggestions in this issue: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/293

Comment: I'd say this has nothing to do with React. It's just ES6 modules. Also I can't find an executable (i.e. function) default export anywhere. Where did you find this ? Can you link the file you are importing from ?